# Glade specify CSS file within XML

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, gtk, glade

I'm learning [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org).
I'd like to define some style classes into a separate CSS file, and "include" this CSS file such that it can be loaded with my application. Currently this is what I'm doing with Python3

```
builder = Gtk.Builder ()
builder.add_from_file ("ui.glade")

cssProvider = Gtk.CssProvider()
cssProvider.load_from_path('css.css')
screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
styleContext = Gtk.StyleContext()
styleContext.add_provider_for_screen(screen, cssProvider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)

window = builder.get_object("window1")
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

I would like to know if it's possible to remove all this Python code that loads the CSS, and just add a line within my `ui.glade` file, something like `<style> css file name here </style>`, such that it will be loaded automatically.

Comment: The GtkBuilder file format does not support embedded CSS yet. Sorry.

Comment: @andlabs Is it planned to be added sooner or later?

Comment: I don't know; sorry. You can ask on the GNOME bugzilla if you want, assuming no one has asked before. Good luck!